# How to detect url, first containing directory with query string and second having simple .aspx file with query string

Tags: asp.net, url, iis, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I have two Pages URLs,

**First one** is WWW.domain.com/test/page.aspx?id=2&URL=3
which is re-written like WWW.domain.com/test/page/2/3/

**Second one** is WWW.domain.com/page.aspx?id=1&URL=2&query=3
which is re-written like WWW.domain.com/page/1/2/3/

Now how can i differentiate these URL because in general both looks same.

**In real first page is in the sub-directory and other is in the root directory**

I have tried a rule which is written below but it is calling for both URL due to regular expression pattern match.

Can any one help me to map these URL, i think both the URL should match by different rules.

```
<rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="^([^/]+)" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="false" />
                    </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/{R:2}.aspx?{R:3}={R:4}" />
            </rule>
```

If you feel any difficulty in understanding kindly let me know. Thanks.